# Pretty Printing in Haskell in 2017

Tags: haskell, pretty-print

The final paragraph of Chapter 5 of [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/writing-a-library-working-with-json-data.html) recommends `Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJ` for pretty printing rather than custom show types, and provides the [originating academic paper](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/bibliography.html#bib.hughes95) for clarifications.  A comment on that also linked to:

- https://hackage.haskell.org/package/FPretty-1.0/docs/Text-PrettyPrint-FPretty.html
- http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/oc/pretty.html

I've looked for examples using Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJ, and have not found much online.  My questions are:

1. Is there a module in the Haskellverse approaching the python ease of "from pprint import pprint as pp; pp(myjson)"?
2. How can I use HughesPJ in a minimum viable example sense that will generate output similar to python's pretty print (in terms of spaces, indentation, etc., on a json object)?

Comment: Doesn't said chapter explain the usage? What issue do you have using `HughesPJ` exactly?

Comment: @deceze, no, the chapter does not cover HughesPJ.  It lays out how to write you own pretty printer for chapter 5, then says:  
"Practical pointers and further reading

GHC already bundles a pretty printing library, Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJ. It provides the same basic API as our example, but a much richer and more useful set of pretty printing functions. We recommend using it, rather than writing your own."

Those richer and more useful set of pretty printing functions that are recommended, are to me, somewhat opaque.

Comment: To pretty-print json, [use the json pretty-printer](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-pretty-0.8.2/docs/Data-Aeson-Encode-Pretty.html)!

Comment: @Benjamin Hodgson, please reopen.  I am not asking for a recommendation or offsite resource, but specifically for a resource to be written as the answer to this question illustrating how to use .Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJ. If you have additionally recommendations in addition to that, that would make an excellent comment.

Comment: Recommendations are already covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761507/which-pretty-print-library (in a not closed question).

Comment: @Mittenchops I suggest you re-word your question. Remove the "Is there a module in the Haskell universe?" question, which clearly _is_ asking for a recommendation. Even after that, I think this question would still be very broad - you're basically asking "How do I use `pretty`?" - so I recommend including some actual code and describing why your attempt didn't work. Stack Overflow works best when you ask specific code questions, rather than broad how-to questions.

Comment: I get that this is closed, but it remains insane to me that if I have something as easy as an html string with embedded newlines and I'm just trying to view the source, I have no discernible way of saying `prettyprint myhtml` and seeing it rendered coherently.  This hurts stackoverflow usability, and closing it and every similar Haskell pretty print question makes what should be an easy task unapproachable and the learning climb that much steeper.